# How to compile Dos Com files in linux?

Tags: linux

I have an ms dos com file that works in the virtual mode under windows. 
And 
I want to compile it and run it under linux .
How to compile dos com files in linux ?
Thank you .

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to "compile" it, it's already compiled as binary code, but you could try to run it using the appropriate Dosbox version for your distro: http://www.dosbox.com/